# Trouble with Rdkit when converting to molecular fingerprints

Tags: rdkit

When attemping to get the rdkit to work i keep getting an argument error i am unsure of how to solve.

```py
mol_list1 = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(i) for i in tqdm(df_database['Ligand SMILES'], desc='Creating mol objects from database Smiles')]
mol_list2 = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(i) for i in tqdm(df_metabolites['Smiles'].dropna(), desc='And now for the metabolites!')]
mfp1 = [AllChem.GetMorganFingerprint(j, 4) for j in tqdm(mol_list1, desc='Getting fingerprints for database mols')]
```

> ArgumentError: Python argument types in
> rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.GetMorganFingerprint(NoneType, int) did
> not match C++ signature: GetMorganFingerprint(class RDKit::ROMol mol,
> unsigned int radius, class boost::python::api::object invariants=[],
> class boost::python::api::object fromAtoms=[], bool
> useChirality=False, bool useBondTypes=True, bool useFeatures=False,
> bool useCounts=True, class boost::python::api::object bitInfo=None,
> bool includeRedundantEnvironments=False)

This is from the third line `GetMorganFingerprint` Imports were;

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem,MACCSkeys
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors 
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem 
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
```

Please help!

Comment: This error usually means that the input to the `GetMorganFingerprint` function is not a proper `rdkit mol` object which in turn means that one of the SMILES in the first list is invalid. Just check your SMILES strings and verify if any element in `mol_list1` is `None`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Im very new at this so could you explain how I do this

Comment: Simply run `None in mol_list1`. If the output is `True` then there's an invalid SMILES string. To find which of the SMILES are invalid, first find the index for them by running something like `indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(mol_list1) if x == None]`. Once you know the index, just fetch those rows from `df_database['Ligand SMILES']` to see the invalid SMILES.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.